# Insert text at specified position (i.e. after 100 characters within <p>, add "Read More")

Tags: jquery

The question title sums it up, i don't know how else to elaborate.
Before anyone mentions the CSS3 property `text-overflow:ellipsis` I can't use that as it won't work when the containing div has several `<p>`s within it.Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (txt.length>100) {
        $(this).text(txt.substring(0,100)+'...');
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bh3ug/)

or maybe :

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (txt.length>100) {
        $(this).html('<span>'+txt.substring(0,100)+'&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="somemore">Read More</a>');
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bh3ug/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin for this awhile back. I don't really maintain it anymore, but it should still work: http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=jTruncate